# How to add an external object as a field panel in Wagtail CMS

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I've a pre-existing Django project where I started a Wagtail-driven app.
In the Django project, I have a model Map which I need to make available also in the wagtail-app.

*Django-project Map class in **model.py***

```
class Map(..):
```

Wagtail-app model.py:

```
class Wagtail-appPage(Page):
    main_image = models.ForeignKey(
       'wagtailimages.Image',
       null=True,
       blank=True,
       on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
       related_name='+'
    )
    map = models.ForeignKey(Map, related_name="map_set", null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField("Post date")
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('date'),
        FieldPanel('intro'),
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
        ImageChooserPanel('main_image'),
        <MapChooserPanel>('map')
    ]
```

My goal is to add the possibility to load map objects in a wagtail panel (for ex. MapChooserPanel()) in the wagtail/admin, as it happens for standard images.

How would you proceed? Does it sound very difficult? I'm totally new to Wagtail..

Thank you in advance for any help you will provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is to register your Map model as a [snippet](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.7/topics/snippets.html), and then to reference it from your page with a [SnippetChooserPanel](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.7/topics/snippets.html#binding-pages-to-snippets).

Good luck!

Comment: thank you for your hint, as soon as I implement it I will set this question as answered! But before I'm trying to solve this second problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635608/how-to-set-the-project-root-url-when-wagtail-is-integrated-as-an-app-in-a-django