# How to set the project root url when Wagtail is integrated as an app in a Django-project

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm integrating Wagtail in a pre-existing Django project.
My project tree is as follows:

```
/adjangoproject/
    /anapp
    /blog/
       urls.py
    /anotherapp
    urls.py
```

My **adjangoproject/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                      url(r'^blog/', include('geonode.blog.urls')),
                      [...]
```

My **adjangoproject/blog/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^cms/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),
)
```

While `[adjangoproject_rooturl]/blog/cms` correctly shows the wagtail admin, the path `[adjangoproject_rooturl]/blog/`
(the base location where the pages of my wagtail blog shall be served) gives:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/
Raised by:  wagtail.wagtailcore.views.serve
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Do you have any Site records set up in the admin, under Settings -> Sites? There should be one created by default, but if you deleted the initial homepage and created a new one to replace it, this will have been lost, and you'll need to set up a new one.

Comment: Thank you man, if you make your comment an answer I'll set the question as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you have a Site record set up in the admin, under Settings -> Sites. There should be one created by default, but if you deleted the initial homepage and created a new one to replace it, this will have been lost, and you'll need to set up a new one.